# Setting default.parallelism in spark-submit command

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-submit

What is the syntax to change the default parallelism when doing a spark-submit job?

I can specify the number of executors, executor cores and executor memory by the following command when submitting my spark job:

```
spark-submit --num-executors 9 --executor-cores 5 --executor-memory 48g
```

Specifying the parallelism in the `conf` file is :

```
spark.conf.set("spark.default.parallelism",90)
```

If I were to change it in the `spark-submit` command, would it be ?:

```
spark-submit --default.parallelism 90
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Spark Documentation on [Launching Application with spark-submit](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#launching-applications-with-spark-submit) the `spark-submit` command has the following syntax:

```
./bin/spark-submit \
  --class <main-class> \
  --master <master-url> \
  --deploy-mode <deploy-mode> \
  --conf <key>=<value> \
  ... # other options
  <application-jar> \
  [application-arguments]
```

In your case you need to add the following if you want to change the mentioned configuration.

```
spark-submit [...] --conf spark.default.parallelism=90
```

Comment: where do we execute this? in cli? I tried this on the master & driver node, but getting command not found